# How to add package dependencies in a pom file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, build-script

How to add just the packages as dependencies, instead of entire module in a pom.xml.

I have a two modules **dataloader** and **assets** (both with packaging type as war). The **assets** have so many packages and the **dataloader** only needs *oms*, *violations*, and *rules* packages from **assets**. How can I add just the three packages that dataloader needs as dependencies in my dataloader pom.xml.

Is there any smart way where we can wrap the three packages from **assets** and add as a single dependency in the **dataloader** pom.xml when we are trying to build the **dataloader** module ?

Comment: You simply can't you have to separate those parts from your war into a separate module...

Comment: thank you for replying. Wondering if I can have a script that gets executed when ever I build the dataloader module and the script will find the required packages from the project and wrap them into a jar and add to the web-inf/lib folder for the dataloader war.